# Diagnostic IIS 8.5 machine on Windows Azure

Tags: azure

I have a deployed windows azure cloud service that has some custom code running in the start setting up 5 websites on IIS.

After some time the azure management portal start listing the WebRoles as unresponsive, but the websites still answer to requests.

if i remote desktop into the machines and do a start stop of w3sv :

```
net stop w3svc
net start w3svc
```

then it get listed as responding again right away.

Is there any log files that could be of interest to look into to figure out why it happends related to Azure Cloud Services and how they report status.

I found this in c:/logs/ :

```
[00000006] [08/02/2014 16:38:38.57] [INFO]  Role cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 is reporting state Ready.
[00000010] [08/02/2014 16:38:39.58] [INFO]  Role cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 has current state Started, desired state Started, and goal state execution status StartSucceeded.
[00000006] [08/02/2014 16:38:43.62] [HEART] WindowsAzureGuestAgent Heartbeat.
[00000006] [08/02/2014 16:38:43.62] [INFO]  Role cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 is reporting state NotReady with sub-status Unresponsive and details Role cannot be reached by the host system..
[00000010] [08/02/2014 16:38:44.63] [INFO]  Role cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 has current state Unresponsive, desired state Started, and goal state execution status StartSucceeded.
[00000004] [08/02/2014 16:38:48.66] [HEART] WindowsAzureGuestAgent Heartbeat.
```

Is there any way to debug why it thinks its unresponsive?

I also found :

```
[00002052:00004500, 2014/08/02, 16:38:40.947, WARN ] HealthTimer for cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 expired.
[00002052:00004500, 2014/08/02, 16:38:40.947, IMPRT] State of cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 changed from RoleStateStarted to RoleStateUnresponsive.
[00002052:00007628, 2014/08/02, 19:30:51.309, IMPRT] State of cc94138f6d274dfd831683f4208b9f90.Ascend.Host.WebRole_IN_0 changed from RoleStateUnresponsive to RoleStateStarting.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect more information to identify the root cause from the following log files:

1. **WaAppAgent** - C:\Logs\AppAgentRuntime.Log
2. **WaHostBootstrapper** - C:\Resources\Directory\$deploymentID.$role.DiagnosticStore\WaHostBootstrapper.log
3. **WaWebHost** - C:\Resources\Directory\$guid.$role\WaWebHost.log
4. **WaIISHost** - C:\Resources\Directory\$deploymentID.$role\WaIISHost.log
5. **IISConfigurator** - C:\Resources\Directory\$deploymentID.$role\IISConfigurator.log
6. **IIS Logs** - C:\Resources\Directory\$guid.$role.DiagnosticStore\LogFiles\W3SVC1
7. **Windows Event Logs** - use Event Viewer

Look for error messages around the same time you see the agent reporting Unresponsive state from the service.

Comment: Tkanks. I have been over all those and there is no errors. The only thing i have right now is the warning on the healthtimer has expired.   I got form Compute SDK team that if the role status check takes longer than 15 sec, this could be the case. I am in the process of finding out if this could be the case.